# Replace expressions by self defined symbols

Tags: replacement

I have a list of expressions like the following:

```
{{X00 ** X10 + X01 ** X10 - X10 ** X01 - X10 ** X00 }, 
 {X01 ** X10 - X10 ** X01 - X02 ** X10}, 
 {X00 ** X12 -  X12 ** X00}, {X01 ** X12 - X12 ** X01}, {X02 ** X13}}
```

where all `Xij` are just symbols. Now suppose we define an expression like

```
[X0j,X1k] := X0j ** X1k - X1k ** X0j.
```

Is it possible to let Mathematica substitute all terms in the list that look like the right side of the last expression by its left side?

If necessary I can change the `Xij`'s in the list to something else.

Comment: `[X0j,X1k]` is not syntactically correct Mathematica.  Could you clarify what you mean by it?  Could you please give an exampe of a possible substitution (I'm a little confused about what you need exactly)?

Comment: Ok the "[" and "]" symbols are occupied by mathematica itself. But that was just an example. We could use anything. terms like X0j ** X1k - X1k ** X0j should just be rephrased by something visual more meaning full.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's represent your bracket expression using the head `bb`, so

```
bb[x, y] == x ** y - y ** x
```

Then we can just use a simple replace rule:

```
{{X00 ** X10 + X01 ** X10 - X10 ** X01 - X10 ** X00 }, 
 {X01 ** X10 - X10 ** X01 - X02 ** X10}, 
 {X00 ** X12 -  X12 ** X00}, {X01 ** X12 - X12 ** X01}, {X02 ** X13}} \
   //. x_ ** y_ - y_ ** x_ :> bb[x, y]

(* ==>
  {{bb[X00, X10] + bb[X01, X10]}, 
   {bb[X01, X10] - X02 ** X10}, 
   {bb[X00, X12]}, {bb[X01, X12]}, {X02 ** X13}}
*)
```

We can automate the conversion between the two representations using

```
toBracket[expr_] := expr //. x_ ** y_ - y_ ** x_ :> bb[x, y]
fromBracket[expr_] := expr /. bb[x_, y_] :> x ** y - y ** x
```

If you wish to have a prettier notiation, you could for example use `AngleBracket` instead of `bb`.  It is formatted like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can enter the brackets using the key sequence <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Comment: Ok thanks! That solved my problem.

Comment: "//." cannot start another line, otherwise the program cannot run.

Comment: @lotus2019 Thanks for pointing that out. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 3):

Mark,

This is not an answer as much as it is a recommendation. I had to manipulate long expressions of non-commutative variables for my PhD going beyond defining a Killing form. If this will be the case for you I really highly recommend the NCAlgebra package someone wrote:

http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/

the manuals are pretty much self explanatory and it will solve many problems (like series expansion etc).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative solution which takes advantage of the support for `Subscript` in NCAlgebra 5.0.0. Unfortunately it does not look as cool as it does once you put that on a Notebook. Try:

```
expr = {{Subscript[x, 0, 0] ** Subscript[x, 1, 0] + 
         Subscript[x, 0, 1] ** Subscript[x, 1, 0] - 
         Subscript[x, 1, 0] ** Subscript[x, 0, 1] - 
         Subscript[x, 1, 0] ** Subscript[x, 0, 0]}, 
        {Subscript[x, 0, 1] ** Subscript[x, 1, 0] - 
         Subscript[x, 1, 0] ** Subscript[x, 0, 1] - 
         Subscript[x, 0, 2] ** Subscript[x, 1, 0]}, 
        {Subscript[x, 0, 0] ** Subscript[x, 1, 2] - 
         Subscript[x, 1, 2] ** Subscript[x, 0, 0]}, 
        {Subscript[x, 0, 1] ** Subscript[x, 1, 2] - 
         Subscript[x, 1, 2] ** Subscript[x, 0, 1]}, 
        {Subscript[x, 0, 2] ** Subscript[x, 1, 3]}}
```

and the single substitution:

```
NCReplaceRepeated[expr, Subscript[x, 0, j_] ** Subscript[x, 1, k_] - 
                        Subscript[x, 1, k_] ** Subscript[x, 0, j_] -> 
                          f[Subscript[x, 0, j], Subscript[x, 1, k]]]
```