# Simplify an expression containing NonCommutativeMultiply

Tags: simplifying-expressions

How does mathematica evaluate the following expression to zero:

```
-a ** (b ** c - c ** b) + b ** (a ** c - c ** a) - 
 c ** (a ** b - b ** a) + (a ** b - b ** a) ** 
  c - (a ** c - c ** a) ** b + (b ** c - c ** b) ** a
```

In the reference of the non commutative multiplication `**` is stated that it is 
assumed to be associative and consequently the expression should be equal to 
zero. However just applying `Simplify[]` doesn't work for me.

Comment: The problem seems to be that Mathematica doesn't consider `**` to be distributive: `a**(b+c)-a**b-a**c` doesn't evaluate to 0, not even with `FullSimplify`.

Comment: Ok. But if this is true, it should be considered as a bug, because in the context of rings the term 'multiplication' referees to something that is distributive and since '-' and '+' are there, too, we should think at least in terms of rings here.

Comment: @Mark This is not a bug.  The system simply doesn't have many operations built-in for non-commutative operators.  `Simplify`/`Expand`/etc. assume complex numbers, not general operators.

Comment: Have you looked at the NCAlgebra package that has been suggested in your last question?  It looks like something exactly for this.

Comment: Ok I wasn't aware of the restrictions of Simplify ect. but on a first look I think the recommended package is what I need.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you need here is actually expanding the expression (i.e. transforming all `(a+b) ** c` type expressions to `a**c + b**c`).  There's no built-in support for this kind of manipulation of non-commutative expressions.  You'd need to implement them yourself, which can be quite a bit of work.

However, instead of bothering with implementing all these simple operations yourself, I recommend using a dedicated package.  [@gpap](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1079/gpap) [suggested](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5446/12) the [`NCAlgebra` package](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/) in an answer to your previous question.

After installing `NCAlgebra` by placing the `NC` directory in my `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications` directory, I could do this:

```
<< NC`
<< NCAlgebra`

expr = -a ** (b ** c - c ** b) + b ** (a ** c - c ** a) - 
  c ** (a ** b - b ** a) + (a ** b - b ** a) ** 
   c - (a ** c - c ** a) ** b + (b ** c - c ** b) ** a

NCExpand[expr]

(* ==> 0 *)
```

Comment: Hmm wen I use the NC package I get NCExpand[Y01 ** Y10 - Y10 ** Y01] =0. Seems ** is interpreted differently here.

Comment: @Mark That is very strange.  It seems `Y01 ** Y10 - Y10 ** Y01` evaluates to 0 when using that package.  `a**b - b**a` doesn't however.  I am not familiar with the package, but I'll try to see what's going on.

Comment: @Mark if you look at the [docs](http://math.ucsd.edu/~ncalgweb/basiccommands.html) of the package, it says: "At present, single-letter lower case variables are non-commutative by default and all others are commutative by default."

Comment: @Mark Originally I suggested using `expr //. e_NonCommutativeMultiply :> Distribute[e]`.  However, this won't work for an expression like `a ** f[b ** (c + d)]`, so I'm removing it.

Comment: NCExpand[x01 ** x10 - x10 ** x01] still gives zero. What kind of indexing can I use? (I have more than 1000 variables so different letters is not an option)

Comment: @Mark again, unfortunately I haven't used the package.  A glance at the docs confirms that only *single-letter* lowercase variables are non-commutative by default.  You can set `x01`, `x10` to be non-commutative using `SetNonCommutative[x01, x10]`.  I'm not sure how the default for all symbols can be changed.  Regarding easy indexing, `x[0, 1] ** x[1, 0] - x[1, 0] ** x[0, 1]` *might* be an easier solution.

Comment: Ok. I wrote an email to the developers. I will post the results here.

Comment: Using SetNonCommutative[] worked. I wrote a little program that put all the thousands of indexed variables into SetNonCommutative[] and then used NCExpand[] to do the job, which it did pretty well. Good package. Robust even on input data >1MB ...

Comment: The newest version of [NCAlgebra](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC) supports `Subscript`. If the base symbol is noncommutative so will be its subscripted version. Things like: `Subscript[x, 0, 1] ** Subscript[x, 1, 0] - Subscript[x, 1, 0] ** Subscript[x, 0, 1]` will work out of the box.