# Simplifying with noncommutative multiplication

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am trying to do some quantum algebra computations in *Mathematica*. Up to now I was able to make the noncommutative multiplication linear and to factorize powers. However, I still have some issues with associativity. In particular, I would like to be able to remove brackets expressions like `a ** ( b ** c )` and get `a ** b ** c`. The reason for that is that I already have a procedure that substitutes `a^2 ** b` to `a ** a ** b`, but this doesn't work when I have brackets `(a ** ( a ** b ))`.
Does anyone know how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Could you provide your procedure? Why do you use noncommutative multiplication `**` only in the last formula?

Comment: Take a look at the NCAlgebra package, like [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5480/simplify-an-expression-containing-noncommutativemultiply/5481#5481)

Comment: I am sorry, that was a typo... I just corrected everything, it's noncommutative multiplication all along.

Comment: @user37905 Maybe there is `*` in the last formula? Otherwise I don't understand because `a ** (a ** b)` automatically converts to `a ** a ** b`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem (if I understand correctly) is that you want to make the following replacements:

```
a * (a * c)  ==> a * a * c   ==> a^2 * c
a * (a ** c) ==> a * a ** c  ==> a^2 ** c
```

The trick is that in the second line, `a * a ** c` is parenthesised as `a * (a ** c)`, where `a * a` is not recognized as `a^2`. Use the following rule:

```
rep = (x_*(x_ ** y__) :> x^2 ** y);
```

> ```
> a*(a ** c)                 (* ==>   a a ** c)        *)
> a*(a ** c ** d) /. rep     (* ==>   a^2 ** c ** d    *)
> a*(b ** a) /. rep          (* ==>   a b ** a     NC-ity is maintained    *)
> ```