# Why can't I define a commutator operator in this way?

Tags: parallelization, operators

I am trying to define some operators I use frequently. For example, I defined a `KroneckerProduct` operator as $\otimes $ as follows:

```
a_⊗b_:=a.b-b.a
```

And this works fine.

Then I want to define a commutator used in quantum mechanics act like follows:

$${\left[ {a,b} \right]_ - } = a.b - b.a$$
$${\left[ {a,b} \right]_ + } = a.b + b.a$$

where `a` and `b` are matrices.

So I naively write the definition in *Mathematica* as follows:

$${\left[ {a{\rm{\_}},b{\rm{\_}}} \right]_ - }: = a.b - b.a$$
$${\left[ {a{\rm{\_}},b{\rm{\_}}} \right]_ + }: = a.b + b.a$$

But this will not work.

1. How do I define the commutator in this form (appearance)?
2. And why does the definition for `a_⊗b_` hold, but the similar definition for commutator `[a_, b_]` does not hold?

---

There is another question which actually should create another post. But I choose just to add it here.

If I defined the `KroneckerProduct` as the operator `⊗` in the way I did, then I found that in parallel computing, I can't simply distribute such a definition of `⊗` like:

```
DistributeDefinitions[⊗]
```

*Mathematica* doesn't allow me to do that. Of course the `Parallelize` will not distribute the `⊗` definition automatically either. So if an expression contains a `⊗`, simply `Parallelize` it, the computation will get stuck and no answer will come out.

So my second question is:

How do I distribute such an operator definition in parallel computing?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no time for a complete answer now, but for the first part, `Notation` package is your friend. See wolfram link [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Notation/tutorial/NotationSymbolizeAndInfixNotation.html)

Answer (score 7):

Maybe it's this that you are looking for.

Using the notation Package you can write:

[image]

I used a image to show these yellow box. To create it, use the notation pallet that Popup when you call the Package.
This is the pallet:

[image]

Use the second button to do your new notation.

More information about this in Wolfram help in [this link](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Notation/tutorial/NotationSymbolizeAndInfixNotation.html).

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment but not a complete answer. From the end

-I don't know how (or if it is possible) to distribute the operation in parallel computing.

-See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5444/), and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5399/) question for defining a commutator.

In particular there is advice in the second one by Szabolics on how to use better notation if you don't like the one below.

-An anticommutator would be sufficiently defined by a rule I think, like so:

```
HoldAll[(l m + m l + l^2 + m m l )] /. {(a_ b_ + b_ a_) -> 
Anitcom[a, b], a_ a_ -> 0, a_^_->0}
```

Where you can define `Anticom` on a case by case basis.